How to get the result of the HTTPrequest in advance and process the result of the request after a certain condition?
Let the HTTPrequest be executed in advance. After moving the mouse to an element on the page, if the request is completed, process the result and open the link in the returned result.
Consider a delay of 1500ms for the time being, wait for the request to be completed, and process the link in the return result.
Can you judge that the HTTPrequest has been completed when opening the request result link without delay?
Request function, get a link to the returned result, and execute the request immediately.
    var jhref;
    function getWebsite(s) {
        let xhrResult = '';
        jhref = 'http://aaa.com';
            GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                method: 'GET',
                url: jhref,
                onload: function (result) {
                    xhrResult = result.status;
                    let domNew = new DOMParser().parseFromString(result.responseText, 'text/html');
                    let linkElement = domNew.querySelectorAll('.item>a')[0];
                    if(linkElement != undefined) {
                        jhref = linkElement.href;
                    } else {
                        xhrResult = 404;
                    }
                },
                onerror: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
            });
    }
          
    getWebsite(text);

Move the mouse to an element to execute the link in the return result, which must be executed after the GET request is completed.
window.open(jhref)


What shall happen if the mouse moves to the element before the HTTPrequest has finished?

In your onload function, you could append linkElement to the current dom and call .click on it.

@HeikoTheißen no real result, it will open the url that define before request

You need an event handler that is executed once when the mouse is moved over the target. This can happen before the HTTPrequest has finished (in which case the original jhref URL will be opened) or afterwards (in which case the jhref contained in the HTTP response will be opened).
The snippet below shows this, it uses the more modern fetch command instead of the XMLHttpRequest.
(Unrelated to this question, but the construction of the jhref URL is a bit tricky, because the parsed HTML contains a relative link, which must be interpreted relative to the base URL from where the HTML was loaded.)
var jhref = "https://httpbin.org/links/1/1";
document.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    location.href = jhref;
  }, {
    once: true
  });
fetch(jhref)
  .then(r => r.text())
  .then(function(html) {
    jhref = new URL(new DOMParser()
      .parseFromString(html, 'text/html')
      .querySelector("a").getAttribute("href"),
      jhref);
  });

<button>Hover to navigate</button>

